# What are the ways to analyze if a critical point is saddle maximum or minimum when det(Hessian)=0?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to finish my homework and I don’t know how to finish the analysis at one point.

I have $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-x^3)$ and finished the critical points $(1,1)$ and $(2/3,10/27)$ and i’m left with $(0,0)$ which has $\det H=0$.

I know it is a saddle point from the graph, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Is it a $2\times 2$ Hessian?

Comment: If $|H|=0$, you can't conlude anything 'a priori'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x,y) = (y-x^2)(y-x^3) = y^2 - x^2y -x^3y - x^5$

You are looking at the critical point at $(0,0)$.  The Hessian essentially gives the second order approximation.  In this case we don't even need to compute it:  we can see the second order approximation is just $f(x,y) \approx y^2$.  This function is concave up along the $y$-axis, but is $0$ along the $x$-axis.  This is why you are seeing the determinant of the Hessian vanishing.

If we want to see how $f$ behaves along the $x$ axis we can just look at $f(x,0) = -x^5$.  This changes sign through the origin (and in fact has a point of inflection there).  So we have a kind of "saddle" behavior.

Comment: i have f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-x^3) and finished (1,1) and (2/3,10/27) and i’m left with (0,0) which has detH=0 ik it is a saddle point from the graph, idk how to prove it